# How to redirect to Login page when users not logged in the application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in my React project. The issue that the app would not redirect to Login page when users not logged in yet.

In my `Home.js` I have
This page allows to only users who have already logged in the app.

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

logout = () => {
  firebase.auth().signOut();

  this.props.history.push("/login");
};

render() {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser === null) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.logout}>
          Google Logoout
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Actually, I use for classifying if the user is logged in or not by `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple one. This can be done by using `onAuthStateChanged` from firebase like so:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
   user ? history.push("/dashboard") : history.push("/login");
   renderApp();
});
```

If there is a user, redirect him to in my case dashboard, if not, redirect him to login.

Comment: nit-picking: you could have a single `renderApp();` after the if/else statement ;)